# How can I receive the current displayed week of google calendar with app-script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I cannot find any property receiving the currently **for the user displayed** calendar week with google apps-script [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app)

What I want to do is:
Extract the start and end date of the days displayed for the user in google-calendar.

What I already archive is to get events of the current week's Monday (so from the perspective of today):

```js
getEventsOfThisWeek(calendarId) {
    calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
    let referenceDay = new Date(); //here I would like to get a day from displayed week 
    let monday = this.getMondayMidnightAM(referenceDay);
    let friday = theís.getFridayMidnightPM(referenceDay)
    let events = calendar.getEvents(monday, friday );

    return events
}


getMondayMidnightAM(ref) {
    let day = ref.getDay();

    let diff = ref.getDate() - day + (day == 0 ? -6 : 1); // adjust when day is sunday

    ref.setDate(diff);
    let mondayMidnight = new Date(ref.toISOString().replace(/T\S{8}/, "T00:00:00"));
    return mondayMidnight;
}
```

So far I understood, that [`isSelected()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#isselected) tells me not if the event is **on screen in the current view**, but rather if the display in all the calendar option is on.

Comment: By the current diplayed week do you eman the week we are currently in (so Su, 30 of January to Sa, 5 of February right now) or the week the user happens to see in his calendar when you run the code (he could be loooking at any week of any year)?

Comment: I mean the calendar page I see as a user. Your second idea. yes I know he could be looking at any week. for example next week or last week. I mean google knows what page to display, how can I get the information in app-script? Is there any property?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @AaronDuniganAtLee how comes?

Comment: For one, there are no documented methods that would do this.  But conceptually, you would need to trigger the script from within the Calendar UI for this to make sense, and there are no features for that.  Compare to SpreadsheetApp and DocumentApp, which allow you to get the user's current cell or cursor selection, but only for the spreadsheet/doc the script is bound to (e.g. try running `SpreadsheetApp.openById(...).getSelection().getActiveRange().getA1Notation()`: you always get A1 even if you have that spreadsheet open and another range selected).  But scripts can't be bound to Calendar.

Comment: Also: How are you triggering the function?  If from a timed trigger or a script bound to a document, how does that script even know if you have the calendar open in the UI?  How would it handle if the user opens two different views of the calendar in different tabs?  You'd somehow need to associate the script with a particular browser session: that only really makes sense for container-bound scripts.

Comment: I thought there are maybe parameters like the  `PropertiesService` properties  (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) , that allow me to access such information. Too bad, that would really help ... any other idea, how to access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Short: It is not possible.**

- The problem with the calendar page you see as a user is that if multiple users have access to the same (e.g. group) calendar, every user might look at at different week.
- The script can only access server-side data that is the same for every user (e.g. event name, guests etc.).
- Only an [Addon](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/calendar) can access some specific information that only the user who installed the Addon sees.
- This information is contained in [object events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/event-objects) that become available when a [manifest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/guides/glossary#manifest_trigger) or [contextual trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/guides/glossary#contextual_triggering) get fired - e.g. when a user creates or edits an event
- However, as you can see in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/event-objects#calendar_event_object) the Calendar Event Objects do not comprise any information about the currently open week, so there is no way to get this information programamtically
- Maybe it is possible to get this data through webscraping, whereby I would not be able to tell you if and how this can be done